# Menu Specifically For Super Users

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, menu, access

Joomla 3.9.20

I allow users to register on my website, they automatically go into a group called 'Training', their parent group is `Registered`, see below;

```
 - Registered
 -- Training
```

I have created a 'Training' menu that is specifically for these users and the access level is set to `Registered`, this allows users to login to the site and view this menu.

The menu is really only applicable to these users, and no other group needs to see or access it.

How can I hide this menu from `Super Users`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a Viewing Access Level called 'Fred' or 'Training Only' and include only the Group 'Training' in this Viewing Access Level.

In your Menu you change your Access Level from 'Registered' to 'Training Only' or 'Fred' or whatever you called it.

It gets confusing with Group and Viewing Access Levels because as shipped they both share the stock names of Registered, Public, Guest etc. but they are not directly connected by that shared name.

Terry

Comment: Thanks for this very clear explanation. I always find it difficult to understand the user and viewing access levels.